# Microsoft (Preview) Outlook Quit Unexpectedly

Tags: macos, ms-office

I got the preview release of Office for Mac and everything works but Outlook. Every time I launch it immediately crashes with

```
Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
```

I can still use Outlook 2011 just fine, so that's what I'm doing but Outlook was the primary reason I wanted to upgrade to the preview release. Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Beta releases.

Comment: This isn't clearly off topic as the general consensus isn't yet for closure. See http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/q/2389/5472

Comment: My initial tests point to the problem being account dependent.
I.e. one mail account crashes, but two other accounts don't.
Accounts are on the same domain hosted on 365.
The oldest account with the most "junk" in it crashes. This account has also been migrated from Exchange 2003 some years ago. The other two, less used and "born" on 365, accounts are stable. Tested on two machines, both running OS X 10.10.2 and Outlook 15.8.1. One installed as 15.8.1. The other one updated from 15.8.0

Comment: Given the answer saying this is fixed in the next version or the other showing it crashes in beta but not production I really think that this can only be resolved by reports on the official beta reporting channel and we can provide no useful answer here, All these comments have to be reported to MS to have any effect. So I think this case should be closed as OT

Answer (score 2):

Updating to 15.8.1 solved the issue.